# phpで画像のExif情報（回転方向）を修正

Tags: php

表題の件に関してですが、

iPhoneのカメラで撮った画像が反転してしまうのを修正するために調べると
phpの `exif_read_data` でexif情報を読み込み、修正できるとあったので
やってみているのですが、なかなかうまくできず質問させて頂きます。

phpマニュアルで `exif_read_data` を調べ、コードを書いてみました。

ただし、下記のコードで最終的に$imageに回転が修正された
画像データが入っているとあるのですが、

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

こちらを書いてページをリロードした時に画面が真っ黒になり、真ん中に小さく白線の四角形が表示されてしまいます。。。
`header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` を書いてリロードした時点で上記の状態になってしまうようです。

```php
$photo = "../../images/".$photo['name'];

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($photo));

$exif = exif_read_data($photo);

if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
                    break;
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
                    break;
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
                    break;
    }
}
```

フレームワークやライブラリなどは何も使用しておらず、使用せずにできればと考えております。

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、、、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` では JPEG としていますが、`imagepng($image);` では PNG として出力しています。これは書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。imagejpeg($image)の間違いでした。ただ、imagejpeg($image)に書き換えても同様に全画面黒背景に真ん中に小さく(1cmほどの)白線で◻︎が表示されていますね。。。

Comment: `$photo` に入っているファイル名ですが、そのファイルは画像(JPEG)なのでしょうか？

Comment: $photo['name']でechoしてもimage0.jpegと出力されています。
ちなみにこのコードを書いているのは画像アップロード後の確認画面なのですが、画像のexif情報を修正して保存したい場合、そもそも画像がフォルダへアップロードされる前に修正をしないといけないんでしょうか。

Comment: 念の為にお聞きしますが、そのアップロード後の image0.jpeg ファイルを画像ビューアで開いた場合、問題なく閲覧可能なのですね？

Comment: <im src="../../images/<?php echo $photo['name']; ?>">
と書いて表示されています。

Comment: 画像の出力(=保存)の問題なのか、単にPHPでの画像指定が間違っているのかの切り分けが必要な気がします。

Comment: cubick♦様　かしこまりました。一度問題を整理しようと思います。